# Why can't the lifetime of a reference be deduced as the shortest of all the contextual possibilities?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here's a code sample where I test two `&str`s and return one of them:

```
fn bad_longest(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> &str {
  if s1.len() >= s2.len() { s1 } else { s2 }
}
```

It didn't compile requesting explicit lifetimes so I provided them:

```
fn longest<'r, 'a, 'b>(s1: &'a str, s2: &'b str) -> &'r str
where
  'a: 'r,
  'b: 'r
{
  if s1.len() >= s2.len() { s1 } else { s2 }
}
```

Now, the following test passes with no problems:

```
static STATIC: &str = "123";

fn main() {
  let auto = "123456";
  let dyn_ = String::from("123456789");
  println!(
    "{}",
    longest(
      longest(STATIC, auto),
      dyn_.as_str()
    )
  );
}
```

Here's my question: aren't the lifetimes which I manually provided obviously deducible from the context? Am I missing any use cases?

Comment: Note that function signature (including lifetimes) is never deduced from its body, to avoid accidental breaking changes. Maybe this fact will be enough.

Comment: @Cerberus a great catch! However, are there any lifetimes between local (which can't be returned by reference anyway) and those provided as function parameters (their possible minimum)? If there are none, I guess I've literally written the shortest lifetime and it can be deduced (but it isn't).

Comment: The returned It could also be just `'a` or just `'b`, or even `'static`. Lifetime elision is just syntactic sugar, just a few simple, easy, rules.

Comment: @rodrigo of course I could return &'static str or whatever else, but are there any problems in deducing the shortest lifetime (min of 'static, 'a and 'b in this example) by default?

Comment: Sure, a new elision rule could be added that reads: _an unspecified return lifetime will be completed with a new lifetime constrained to be as long as any input lifetime._ That would solve your particular case, and would be even backwards compatible. Whether this is a good idea or not... I have no opinion yet.

Comment: But if you worry about the ergonomics of your current solution, note that the _rusty_ way to write your functions would just be: `fn longest<'a>(s1: &'a str, s2: &'a str) -> &'a str` and let the lifetime subtyping do its magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elided lifetimes in a function signature are never deduced from how they are used. There are some [simple rules for inferring elided lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html), which are based entirely on the signature itself:

> - Each elided lifetime in the parameters becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.
> - If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.
>
> In method signatures there is another rule
>
> - If the receiver has type &Self or &mut Self, then the lifetime of that reference to Self is assigned to all elided output lifetime parameters.

Your function has two non-`self` arguments, so none of these rules can give a lifetime for the return value, so explicit lifetimes are required.